# how to add pinch zoom functionality to dynamically created image in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, dynamically-generated, pinchzoom

I am creating images dynamically and want to add drag-drop and pinch zoom functionality to the app
Here is the xaml code which i want to implement in the c#-

```
<Image  Width="100" Height="100" Name="transform" Source="/PhoneApp22;component/Images/abc.png" >
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform2"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
                                     DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Image>
```

Comment: Old post, but works well. Give it a shot: http://sharpgis.net/post/2012/01/17/Building-A-Multi-Touch-Photo-Viewer-Control.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, this might help

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/windows-phone-7-multi-touch-panzoom.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70449/Image-Manipulation-in-Multitouch-Development